# Positive definiteness of matrix with special structure

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Let $i' \in \{1, \dots, N\}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ a symmetric function with the following properties:

1. $a_{i,i} = \alpha > 0$ for all $i \neq i'$.
2. $a_{i',i'} = \alpha' > 0$.
3. $a_{i,j} = \beta > 0$ for all $i,j \neq i'$, that is, the off-diagonal elements (excluding row and column $i'$) all equal $\beta$.
4. $a_{i,i'} = a_{i',i} = \beta' > 0$ for all $i \neq i'$, that is, the off-diagonal elements of row and column $i'$ all equal $\beta'$.

Is $A$ positive definite?

Comment: Start with ${\bf A} = (\alpha - \beta) {\bf I} + \beta {\bf 1} {\bf 1}^\top$ and update it till you have the specified matrix.

Comment: Hint: You can assume WLOG that $i'=N$ (using conjugation by a transposition matrix).

Comment: @JeanMarie I started with the definition of a positive-definite matrix, that is, trying to evaluate $x^TAx$ but I didn't make much progress

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I can suggest defining a vector $\mathbb{1}'$ such that it has a single $1$ in row $i'$, then having $A = (\alpha - \beta)\mathbf{I} + \beta \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^T + (\alpha' - \alpha -2 \beta' + 2 \beta) \mathbf{1}'{\mathbf{1}'}^T + (\beta' - \beta) \mathbf{1}{\mathbf{1}'}^T + (\beta' - \beta) \mathbf{1}'\mathbf{1}^T$

Comment: @yshicht I would just call such vector ${\bf e}_{i'}$. Try to write it in the form ${\bf A} = (\alpha - \beta) {\bf I} + {\bf U} {\bf D}{\bf U}^\top$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo not sure how to do that. Can you give me a hint?
And what would be the next step?

Comment: @yshicht Sorry, I misled you with $\bf D$, which makes it look diagonal.  In fact, the matrix is not diagonal, as the southeastern 2x2 block is anti-diagonal.  For the columns of $\bf U$, look at your previous comment and you will find them.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what do you mean by southeastern 2x2 block? Is there an algorithm to find that decomposition? And what would be the next step, assuming I obtain that decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $N\ge3$. We may assume that $i'=N$. Then
$$
A=\pmatrix{M&\beta'e\\ \beta'e^T&\alpha'}
$$
where $e$ denotes the vector of ones in $\mathbb R^{N-1}$ and $M=(\alpha-\beta)I+\beta ee^T$. Pick any $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ orthogonal matrix $Q$ whose last column is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N-1}}e$. Then
$$
\pmatrix{Q^T\\ &1}A\pmatrix{Q\\ &1}
=\pmatrix{(\alpha-\beta)I_{N-2}\\ &\alpha+(N-2)\beta&\beta'\sqrt{N-1}\\ &\beta'\sqrt{N-1}&\alpha'}.
$$
It follows that $A$ is positive definite if and only if
$$
\alpha>\beta\quad\text{and}\quad\left[\alpha+(N-2)\beta\right]\alpha'> (N-1)(\beta')^2.
$$

Comment: [+1] Excellent. I had guessed this condition $\alpha > \beta$ but not the other one !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the state of my attempts.

As it is very late for me (CET $\approx$ 1:00), I must go to bed. I will reconsider the question tomorrow and/or maybe find counterexamples.

Let us assume that

$$\alpha > \beta \tag{0}$$

Let us take the handy notation $A \succ 0$ for the expression of the definite positiveness of matrix $A$.

In this reference
([Necessary and sufficient conditions for rank-$1$ update of positive definite matrix to be positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175012/305862)) one finds the following Q/A (I have slightly modified the text):

Question : Given $A \succ 0$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ for  $A + \lambda u u^\top \succ 0$ ("rank-one update" of positive definite matrix is still positive definite).

Answer : According to the Sherman-Morrison formula, $\det(A+\lambda uu^T)>0$  iff $1+\lambda u^TA^{-1}u>0$. Then the required condition is

$\lambda >\dfrac{-1}{u^TA^{-1}u}\tag{1}$.

(End of approximate quotation).

The first step I see is to realize that we can take $i'=N$ by a right and left multiplication of $A$ by the transposition matrix exchanging precisely $i'$ and $N$ ; this conjugation operation doesn't change the eigenvalues of $A$.

In this way we can assume that, using block notation:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}A'&\beta'\mathbb{1}\\ \beta'\mathbb{1^T}&\alpha'\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

where $\mathbb{1}$ is the $(N-1) \times 1$ column vector whose entries are equal to $1$.

This $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ upper block of $A$ can be written under the form:

$$A'=\underbrace{(\alpha - \beta)I}_{\succ 0}+\beta \mathbb{11}^T,\tag{3}$$

which is a rank-one update of a psd matrix, itself psd because criteria (1) is fullfilled (it is computed as $\beta > \frac{-(\alpha - \beta)}{N-1}$ which is true because of assumption (0).

The interlacing theorem says that if $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_{N-1}$ are the eigenvalues of block  $A'$, and $\mu_1 \ge \mu_2 \ge \cdots \ge \mu_{N}$ the eigenvalues of the "bordered" matrix $A$, then:

$$\mu_1 \ge \lambda_1 \ge \mu_2 \ge \lambda_2 \cdots \ge \lambda_{N-1} \ge \mu_n$$

But here we cannot go further because nothing can guarantee that $mu_1 >0$, the necessary and sufficient condition for $A$ being $\succ 0$.